# how to add column headers to a listview

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a listview built and styled the way I want it.  Now I am simply trying to add column headers to it, but it seems to be more difficult than I imagined.  Is it necessary to add some sort of datagrid to this xaml model to get column headers, or is there just something very basic I can add?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PlayerOC, Mode=TwoWay}" AlternationCount="2">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>  
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="_Border"
                                Padding="0"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                            
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#19f39611"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#19000000"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>                        
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{Binding RowColor}"  >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerNumber}" Padding="5" Width="50" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerName}"  Padding="5"  Width="200" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the usual way of adding columns to the ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: It works.  I tried this before but I thought I had to remove the data template holding the stack panel, which completely broke down the model.  Thanks.  You got me to look at this a different way.

Comment: Actually, since I already have an Itemsource, I don't even need the DisplayMemberBinding attribute.  All I need are labels for the columns.